# rc-calendar detect month change in date calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

rc-calendar: https://github.com/react-component/calendar

Is there a way to detect the change of month on clicking the next/previous buttons as labeled in the image below:

[image]

**My use case**: I need to fetch all the available dates in a month on clicking next month and disable the unavailable dates in that month.

**Code**: https://codepen.io/sachiv/pen/WBNXLp

**PS**: There is a prop `onChange` which detects change only on the selection of a date and not just month change.

Comment: Try the `onPanelChange` method, maybe that is called when the month is changed.

Comment: kindly share you code.

Comment: @Titus `onPanelChange` is called when picker panel mode is changed not on month change.
@costaloktopus added codepen link